# Golden Layout: how to increase Header Tabs height

Tags: javascript, css, web, layout

I tried to implement [GoldenLayout](https://golden-layout.com/) but it seems not possible to change height of Tabs placed inside heading of each window.

There is a CSS Class with a fixed height of 20px in original theme `.lm_header` but after this, height is set by JS directly as *inline style*.

I tried the following rule

```
.lm_header {
  height: 40px !important;
}
```

But it is a simple override of JS style and is not complete because of position of bottom pane (please see [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/rgmswer7/3/)).

Is there a **standard method** to change size of different elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For tab sizes, you need to set the `dimensions.headerHeight` property on the [configuration object](https://www.golden-layout.com/docs/Config.html) you pass to GoldenLayout, *and* adjust the stylesheet.

JS:

```
 var myLayout = new GoldenLayout({
    dimensions: {
            headerHeight: 46
        },
        content:[{
            type: 'row',
            content:[{
                type: 'component',
                componentName: 'test-component'
            },{
                type: 'component',
                componentName: 'test-component'
            }]
        }]
    });
```

CSS:

```
.lm_tab {
   height: 40px !important;
 }
```

Bare Minimum:
[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rgmswer7/6/)

**Update**

To make it all look nice, update the `line-height` for `.lm_tab`, change the `height` of `.lm_close_tab`, and change the `top` position for `.lm_controls`.

CSS:

```
.lm_tab {
  height: 40px !important;
  line-height:40px;
}

.lm_close_tab {
  height: 35px !important;
}

.lm_controls {
  top:13px;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/jholt456/rgmswer7/7/)

Comment: a bit tricky (need to manually set content top offset in css and also header height in css) but effectively it runs... maybe is useful also to set `line-height:40px;` ot vertical align text

Comment: For sure. For my uses I update a few more styles to make everything line up. See my recent update.